# Is there way to prevent defining user defined destructor of Derived class

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there way to prevent defining user defined destructor of Derived class
I hope developers can't define user defined destructor of derived class of Class I made. My class supports some functions and users can utilize my class functions inheriting my class.

But defining custom destructor in derived class is dangerous, so I hope derived class has only default destructor.

I think I should make some macros about defining class, but I can't know how to. Or compile time make error when derived class has user defined destructor. (But I don't know how to do this)

---

Edited

```
class Manager;
class A
{
    friend class Manager;
    protected:
    virtual ~A()
    {
    }
};

class B : public A
{
    protected:
    virtual ~B()
    {
    }
};

class Manager
{
    std::vector<A*> pointers;
    static void DestoryInstance(size_t index)
    {
       delete pointers[index];
       ~~~~
    }  
};

~~~
DestoryClass::DestoryInstance(1); // i want this
A* pointerA = new B(); 
B* pointerB = new B(); 
delete pointerA;  // error
delete pointerB;  // error
```

but if other developer define derived class like this

```
class C : public A
{
    public:
    virtual ~C()
    {
    }
};
C* pointerC = new C(); 
delete pointerC ;  // this works
```

i don't want this.
and prevent this at Parent class A

---

Sorry, This is idiot question.
Thinking what define derived class's destructor was dangerous is idiot

Comment: *"defining custom destructor in derived class is dangerous"* - this is a rather strange statement. What makes you think it is dangerous?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem, can you clarify at a high level why you think this is necessary. How do you know the derived classes won't have states which need to be destructed in a non-trivial way?

Comment: There is no way to do this. If it is really the case that a user defined destructor might break your class then you haven't defined your class correctly. Or you could just be mistaken. I think you need to show your code.

Comment: Smells like "why you need virtual destructor if your class is being inherited from if you delete from base pointer" issue, and a fundamental misunderstanding how a trivial destructor, a non-trivial one and a user-defined destructor actually differ. In the sense that any non-trivial member of the inheriting class already requires that virtual destructor, and not just user-defined ones.

Comment: In fact all the Derived classes must have `virtual destructor` .

Comment: Write in the documentation that you should not create a destructor

Comment: @foragerDev That is not true. Only derived classes which objects are destroyed in a polymorphic way need virtual destructors.

Comment: @user7860670  can you check my post again, i add what i want exactly

Comment: @M.A can you check my post again, i add what i want exactly

Comment: Your destructor is _protected_, therefore, it may not be accessed from outside of the class hierarchy by default. If you need this functionality, you need to make those entities that want to invoke the destructor _friends_.